# C# MVC Add multiples relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm kind new in the MVC world and I am stucked on a situation that seems pretty simple.

I have a model named Company, and each Company can have many Contacts (name and phone).

What I want is to display a first set of fields for a Contact and a Add Another link that adds the html fields for a new contact.

How can I do that? I know that I can create the fields using JS but how can I send this to my controller? Is there a MVC-way yo do that?

I'm using EF as well

Comment: What kind of ORM are you using? Dapper? Hibernate? Straight SQL? The answer will depend slightly. The simple answer is to have a `CompanyId` field in each contact.

Comment: In general you can bind elements from your html form to your controller actions parameters by name. So if you add new fields with js insert them with propper names (little harder with collections) and implement a POST method for that form that updating your model. Take a look here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ajax calls to talk to your controllers through js.

jQuery

```
var controlName = '/YourControlerName/';
$.getJSON(controlName + 'GetTelss', 
       function (data)`
{
  /// update your ui   
});
```

});

MVC

```
public ActionResult GetTels() 
{     
  return Json(yourDAta,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```